# Spring is autowiring custom bean into its own class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a bean:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper jsonMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

The problem is that while it's being injected into my classes, at the same time it's injected into one of Spring classes since autowiring by type is performed. I don't want WRAP_ROOT_VALUE to be set in the bean that Spring class is using. Is there any options to keep Spring from autowiring it into its classes besides not using beans in this case at all?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `name` attribute in your [@Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation. Then it'll only be injected into classes that make reference to this name.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I think it will work only in the case of autowiring by name.

Comment: And what's the problem with that?

Comment: I thought that to achieve autowiring by name when annotations are used I should add "@Qualifier" in addition to "@Autowired" annotation or in another way modify the place where the object is being injected. But I can't do that in Spring class. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, but you said that you didn´t want this class to be injected on the Spring class.

Comment: Yes, but since I can't modify @Autowired used in Spring class, autowiring by type will be done and my bean will be injected there.